# OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext.ClientId and Parameters are null after Publish

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

### Server Side Code

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string clientId;
            string clientSecret, deviceId;
            string appId = context.Parameters["applicationId"];//renamed from applicationName
            string version = context.Parameters["version"];
            deviceId = context.Parameters["deviceId"];//renamed from applicationName

            context.OwinContext.Set("appId", appId);
            ApiAppClient client;

            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
            {
                var query = context.Parameters.Where(x => x.Key == "client_id");
                if (query.Any())
                {
                    clientId = query.FirstOrDefault().Value?[0];
                }

            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
            {
                //Remove the comments from the below line context.SetError, and invalidate context 
                //if you want to force sending clientId/secrects once obtain access tokens. 
                //context.Validated();
                context.SetError($"Missing ClientId.");
                ////context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
```

### Client Side Code

```
POST https://example.com/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 258

client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz&applicationId=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&username=me&password=somthing&grant_type=password&deviceId=5545555&version=3.2.1.89
```

I have a strange case for above OAuth process ClientId is null as well as Parameters is empty.

1. The above code works fine on all of our developer machines.
2. Compiled Version of Web API also works if hosted in IIS on Developer Machine.
3. But When I try to host Web API on my remote server it always gives error "Missing ClientId".
4. It uses to work perfectly on the same server before upgrading NuGet packages.
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 3.0.1.0 upgraded to 3.1.0.0
   Microsoft.Owin.Security  3.0.1.0 upgraded to 3.1.0.0
   And All Unity Packages

Comment: I have also gone through changes [comparison](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/compare/v3.0.1...v3.1.0) from old to the new version but I didn't find any changes that could create the mentioned case.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, If I am at the right place to raise this issue? Or no one is in the mood to help me out? I tried my all efforts in resolving this bug but no luck